# Update PDO bind key and values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

so I recently switched to use pdo instead of mysqli. now I have a question about binding key values with mysqli. I looped through it escaped the key's and values and used them in my queries now I want to do the same thing in pdo but this isn't working and I don't know why this is my code:

```
foreach($userdata as $key => $value){
    $sql = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET :key = :value WHERE `id` = :userid");
    $sql->execute(
        array(
            'key' => $key,
            'value' => $value,
            'userid' => $userid
        )
    );
}
```

ofcourse there's more code to see if it needs update and other type of inputs that need more validation but this is the main query i used but without binding. is this possible with pdo and binding parameter's and values? 
this is the error i'm getting:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'username' = 'sjerdus' WHERE `id` = '2''
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? It doesn't look like you're doing any [error checking](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php).

Comment: try using ':key' => $key etc... note the " : " not sure if it makes a difference but i do it always that way

Comment: Yes @JayBlanchard this si the error message SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''username' = 'sjerdus' WHERE `id` = '2''

Comment: @Shaeldon The ":" is optional. You can put it or not, it's the same result.

Comment: You cannot alias columns (`:key`), you must state them just as you did with `id`.

Comment: @Mr.Blackus much appreciate that information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have this error because you tried to update a field named dynamically. The `SET :key = ...` can't work because when the parameter will be replaced by its value, it will be escaped (and quoted) by PDO.

If you want to put a variable field name that will be updated, you have to manually concatenate the field name, but you'll have to check for the security yourself.

Try something like this :

```
//Security checks for $field variable...

$sql = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET " . $field . " = :value WHERE `id` = :userid");
$sql->execute(
    array(
        'value' => $value,
        'userid' => $userid
    )
);
```

Comment: so it is impossible to bind field names with pdo? that's a pity

Comment: Nope because prepared statements are not only here to substitute parameters. Query is prepared server side to be executed more than once with different parameters, but the "core" of the query (tables and fields that are queried) doesn't change.

Comment: isn't it a design flaw? seems more then likely to me that fields in a query could change especially if you don't wan't to write 100 if else statements

Comment: Truth is, RDBMS do a lots of things to optimize queries. You should read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter/15990488#15990488) by @IMSoP that is much more complete on why you can't have field or table name as bound parameters.

Comment: Hey so how do i escape a string without mysql or mysqli since quote does the same sanitizing as bind it gives the same error.

Comment: As your variable will contain a field name, you can easily compare it against a white list or something like this.

Answer (score -2):

Here is you could do. I assume that the $userid you have provided is an integer. Where as when you use params in `execute()` directly. They are considered as string.

```
foreach($userdata as $key => $value){
    $sql = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET :key = :value WHERE `id` = :userid");
    $sql->bindParam(':key', $key);
    $sql->bindParam(':value', $value);
    $sql->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
    $sql->execute()
    );
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php